# Does Oracle support table-level & column-level permissions?

Tags: oracle, permissions, vpd

If there is a customer table, and some extra-private/secure information like SSN is there, should I create another table to store such information and lock that table so only certain people can view it even though it's strictly one-to-one? or can columns be locked too from unauthorized viewing based on rights?

Even if both types of security mechanism do exist, is one preferred over the another? I might have said something very vague but I've used SQL Server more often.

Answer (score 6):

Create a view which simply selects all the other columns form the table in question excluding the columns that you don't want the people to have access to.  Give them rights to query the view and not the table.

Answer (score 6):

You can grant [column level privileges](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9013.htm#i2062455) for INSERT, REFERENCES, and UPDATE, but a standard grant cannot be used to limit SELECT privileges on a specific column.

You can do column level masking with a [Virtual Private Database](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/focus-areas/security/index-088277.html) (VPD) policy restricting columns using the sec_relevant_cols parameter.  The feature required Enterprise Edition.

mrdenny is right, the other way to do this is to create a view which does not select the column or does, but masks it.

Comment: I'll remove my info about column level permissions.